# Amazon Connect - Is it possible to key in numbers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I have been working on Amazon Connect for a bit and have successfully implemented a few use cases.
Is there a capability in Amazon Connect to key in a set of digits (say a credit card number, social id, or customer id) using the key pad? I have been able to do this using Lex Voice but not key pad.

This is important as users may not be comfortable using Lex / Voice for sensitive information. More specifically, I am asking about the Contact flows, "Get Customer Input" block and if there is any way to accept a series of digits from key pad.

Comment: Support for using keypad/DTMF input to a Lex bot invoked from an Amazon Connect contact flow is now enabled. People that interact with the bot can now speak an utterance or use their keypad for the intent. If you want to support numeric input to the bot, just add a sample utterance to the bot that is the number you want to use for the intent, such as Two so people can press 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can "Store customer input" block to retrieve information from customer key pad. Please do explore the block which has currently support of retrieving

1. Phone number
2. Customer input (Which could be encrypted using your own key). So can be used for ssn, credit card, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In contact flow design you can add "Get Customer Input" from left side interact panel.

In get customer input block, you can provide Option as the number you want to take the input from.

Below is the image to take the customer input such as 1,2,3, so on using DTMF.

[image]